# Passing specific model from Javascript to MVC Action using Jquery.get()

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm having some issues returning a model to an MVC action that receives an specific model.

This is the JavaScript code:

```
var dataFilter =
{
    Node: 1,
    Name: "John"
}

$.get("MyController/MyAction", { info: dataFilter }, function (data) {
      $("#result").html(data);
});
```

This is my MVC model:

```
public class MyCommonFilter
{
       public int? Node { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public IEnumerable<int> HierarchyIds { get; set; }                                       
       public IEnumerable<int> ProviderIds { get; set; }
}
```

This is my action:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(MyCommonFilter info)
{
    ...
}
```

When I try it the values for the "info" parameters are always null. What's wrong with this? I read that MVC can detect the properties and converted them automatically to my MyCommonFilter model.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC framework can certainly has a powerful type inference capabilities, but it does need the developer to be a little sympathetic towards it.

Currently the resulting URL and query string from your jQuery `.get()` function is:

```
/Home/MyAction?info[Node]=1&info[Name]=John
```

This is because you are actually sending the following JSON object:

```
{
    info: {
        Node: 1,
        Name: "John"
    }
}
```

... and the ASP.NET MVC framework almost understands it!

---

The ASP.NET MVC framework doesn't need you to provide the parameter name, so if you change the data parameter in your jQuery `.get()` function to match the following it should work!

```
$.get("MyController/MyAction", dataFilter, function (data) {
    $("#result").html(data);
});
```

**Example 1:** dataFilter defined using an object literal (JSON)

```
var dataFilter =
{
    Node: 1,
    Name: "John"
}

$.get("MyController/MyAction", dataFilter, function (data) {
    $("#result").html(data);
});
```

**Example 2:** dataFilter defined using dynamic properties

```
var dataFilter = new Object()
dataFilter.Node = 1
dataFilter.Name = "John"

$.get("MyController/MyAction", dataFilter, function (data) {
    $("#result").html(data);
});
```

Comment: I understand your point, but now what if I have javascript object and not as json? like for example: var dataFilter; dataFilter.Node =1; dataFilter.Name = "John", is there anything I should change in the get()? thanks for the answer

Comment: Nope. JSON (or JavaScript Object Notation) is the shorthand for describing JavaScript Objects. The jQuery `.get()` function should take any JavaScript object, no matter how it was declared, as the it's data parameter.